# RxJS: http requests on delay

Tags: angular, ionic2, rxjs

I am just migrating one of my applications to Angular 2 and with it comes RxJS.

I want to refresh my data from server every 5s. At first I figured to do something like this:

```
Observable.timer(0,5000).flatMap(() => this.http.get(url))
```

But if the http request takes more than 5 seconds, another one gets sent. I would like it to wait 5s after http request is finished not after it is created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `expand` Operator to create a new Observable when the source emits an item.

```
let myRequest = this.http.get(...);
let pollingSubscription = myRequest
 .expand(() => Observable.timer(5000).flatMap(() => myRequest));
 .subscribe();
```

[Docs for expand](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/expand.md)

Litte bit offtopic but maybe you should look into something like [LongPolling](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-01-http-long-polling/)

Comment: This sounds perfect, will try it in today. As for websockets, unfortunately we are working with a fixed backend.

Comment: LongPolling have nothing to do with Websockets ;)

Answer (score 1):

One approach you can adopt is

```
RequestGet(){
     this.http.get(url)
          .subscribe(e=>{
              // check if response get or not properly
              // if yes call another method
              this.againRequest();
          })
  }
  againRequest(){
    setTimeout(e => {
      this.RequestGet()
    }, 5000)
  }
```